# How to overload an Odata V2 controller method to accept multiple values as parameters?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, odata

I am new in ASP.NET MVC web development. I am just trying to overload a simple odata controller method for several days but failing again and again. I want to know the mystery behind this. Please help me...

This is my EducationInfo Model class...

```
public partial class EducationInfo
{
    [Key]
    public int EducationID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserID")]
    public int UserID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string EducationLevel { get; set; }

    public string Department_Group { get; set; }

    public string InstituteName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Board_University_Name { get; set; }

    [StringLength(30)]
    public string Duration { get; set; }

    public DateTime PassingYear { get; set; }

    [StringLength(30)]
    public string Result { get; set; }

    public virtual UserInfo UserInfo { get; set; }
}
```

And here is one of my EducationInfoesController GET methods which accepts `EducationID` as parameter

```
// GET: odata/EducationInfoes(5)
    [EnableQuery]
    public SingleResult<EducationInfo> GetEducationInfo([FromODataUri] int key)
    {
        return SingleResult.Create(db.EducationInfoes.Where(educationInfo => educationInfo.EducationID == key));
    }
```

I want to overload this method in a such way that it might take 2 parameters [e.g. GetEducationInfo(int UserID, string EducationLevel)] and return only a single result based on the combination of two parameters (UserID and EducationLevel).

I have already tried to overload this method by following code...

```
// GET: odata/EducationInfoes(5, "bachelor")
    [EnableQuery]
    public SingleResult<EducationInfo> GetEducationInfo([FromODataUri] int key, string eLevel)
    {
        return SingleResult.Create(db.EducationInfoes.Where(educationInfo => educationInfo.UserID == key && educationInfo.EducationLevel == eLevel));
    }
```

But when I'm sending GET requst to my WebService by this URL `http://localhost:10194/odata/EducationInfoes(5, "Bachelor")`, I'm getting this message:

> No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:10194/odata/EducationInfoes(5,"Bachelor")'.

If I change the default method to the following...

```
// GET: odata/EducationInfoes(5)
    [EnableQuery]
    public SingleResult<EducationInfo> GetEducationInfo([FromODataUri] int key)
    {
        return SingleResult.Create(db.EducationInfoes.Where(educationInfo => educationInfo.UserId== key));
    }
```

and requesting using this url `http://localhost:10194/odata/EducationInfoes(3)` and getting this message

> The action 'GetEducationInfo' on controller 'EducationInfoes' returned a SingleResult containing more than one element. SingleResult must have zero or one elements.
>   this message is returned because every single user has multiple Educational Information stored in EducationInfo table.

But I must have to get every EducationInfo result separately or as single result based on UserID and EducationLevel but not based on EducationID. Please help me...

Comment: Have you tried?: http://localhost:10194/odata/EducationInfoes/5/Bachelor. It's just an OData route, not an OData "Function/Action".